# NDK-Use of .a file in C file

Tags: c, makefile, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I'm trying to use a .a file in my C code to use in Java (sorry for my bad English). I created myself a  static library named `libtest.a`. now when i include files present in that library in gives me error as no such file or directory.

i have put the `libtest.a` in the same folder where my `Android.mk` and `Application.mk` resides

C-code:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <jni.h>
#include <exp.h> //the header in libtest.a
```

And this is my makefile:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libtest
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libtest.a

include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := socket
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := source/interface.c source/file.c
LOCAL_LDFLAGS += libtest.a  

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

When I compile it, I get the following error

```
error: exp.h: No such file or directory
```

I want to use the .a without it's code so I hope I'm clear enough.

Comment: What do you mean by "the header in libtest.a"?

Comment: the exp.h file is present in libtest.a

Comment: Headers cannot be in the static library. Headers describe WHAT IS in the static library for the code that tends to use it.

Comment: i have changed my library to shared library...
nw i am getting error:undefined reference to function()i have made my makefile like: **LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir) include $(CLEAR_VARS) LOCAL_MODULE := libtest LOCAL_SRC_FILES := source/libtest.so include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY) include $(CLEAR_VARS) LOCAL_MODULE := socket LOCAL_SRC_FILES := source/interface.c source/file.c LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := libtest LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../libtest/jni/include include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)**
the function()is present inside the exp.h

Comment: Use dlopen() and dlsym() to get pointer to your function from the shared library.

Comment: by using **LOCAL_LDLIBS := -ldl** also,it's not working.......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as i have changed my .mk file

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libtest
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libtest.a
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../libtest/jni/include
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := socket
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := source/interface.c source/file.c
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES += libtest
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are *no* header files in .a file, only the compiled code which is essentially a stream of bytes, not the encoded .h-files . This it NOT Java. To use your `libtest.a` you must supply the `exp.h` file and whatever the dependent header files are.

You should use `LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES` for that.

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := libtest
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libtest.a
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := socket
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := source/interface.c source/file.c
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES += libtest

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Comment: as per your answer i have removed the LOCAL_LDFLAGS += libtest.a line and added this LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES += libtest, but still i am getting the errors.

Comment: You should place ``exp.h`` in the same folder as your .c file that includes it.

Comment: @Sergey K.....any clue why the conversion of freeimage.a to freeimage.so doesnt work?

Comment: Why do you need the conversion? Just link the freeimage.a to your project and you will be able to use it.